# Cargar un combox con datos de una base de datos laravel y vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

tengo el siguiente combobox o select que deberia cargarse con datos de una consulta:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="idcategoria">
  <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id" :value="categoria.id" v-text="categoria.nombre"></option>
</select>
```

este es el metodo que deberia hacer que se cargue el combobox, utilizo el console.log para probar que mis datos se estan recibiendo y si puedo visualizarlos en la consola pero no cargan en el combobox:

```
selectCategoria(){
                let me=this;
                var url= '/categoria/selectCategoria';
                axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    var respuesta= response.data;
                    me.arrayCategoria = respuesta.categorias;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
```

este es el metodo del controller que me devuelve los datos de la base de datos para cargarlos en el select

```
 public function selectCategoria(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
    $categorias= Categoria::where('condicion','=','1')->select('id','nombre')
    ->orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();

    return ['categorias', $categorias];
}
```

Comment: Intenta modificar el return en tu controlador a `return ['categorias' => $categorias];`

Comment: gracias si funciono